# Need to create video element via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I need your help , i need to rewrite this code to javascript:

```
<video width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" id="player1" '.$img.'>
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="'.$manifest.'" />
</video>

<script>

var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
$("#player1").height(viewportHeight);

$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(media, node, player) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode:' + media.pluginType);
    }
});
</script>
```

So i need to construct video element dynamically and then apply mediaelementplayer to this element.

Please help me , thanks!

Comment: I don't think you searched for a solution by yourself.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_video_create

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var winWidth=$(window).width();
    var winHeight=$(window).height();
    $("body").append("<video width='"+winWidth+"' height='"+winHeight+"'><source   src='"+$manifest+"' type='video/mp4'></source></video>");
});`
```